# Counting the Number of Ways a Game Can End

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have a game:

- At the start of the game, the score = 0
- There is a 0.45 probability that the next score = score + 1
- There is a 0.45 probability that the next score = score -1
- There is a 0.1 probability that the next score = score

**My Question:** Suppose my current score is 6. After 15 turns, how many possible ways can my score be? For example:

```
  score_after_15_turns possible_ways
1                    6        x ways
2                    7        y ways
3                    8        z ways
4                    9        w ways
5                  ...           ...
```

**What I tried so far:**

- I know that after 15 turns, the maximum score can be 6+15  = 21 and the minimum score can be 6-15 = -9 . This means that within 15 turns, I can get a score anywhere between -9 to 21 included
- Suppose I consider the following situation: If my current score is 6, in 15 turns, how many ways can I end up with a final score of 6?
- One of these ways could be : 13 stationary steps (S), 1 forward step (F), 1 backwards step (B)

I think I can use the following combinatorial formula (multinomial coefficient) for this:

$${n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m}
 = \frac{n!}{k_1!\, k_2! \cdots k_m!} $$

$$\text{Where:}\ \quad \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i = n$$

For example, 13 stationary steps (S), 1 forward step (F), 1 backwards step (B):

$$\frac{(F+B+S)!}{F! \cdot B! \cdot S!} = \frac{(1+1+13)!
}{1! \cdot 1! \cdot 13!} = 210 $$

But this is just one way to end up with a score of 6 after 15 turns (conditional on starting with a score of 6). There are still many other ways that this is possible. And this is still not even taking into consideration the probabilities involved with obtaining these sequences.

And this is not even taking into consideration the other final scores possible after 15 turns.

Is there a more compact way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What about the other $0.05$?

Comment: Your probabilities don’t sum to 1.

Comment: @Paul Tanenbaum and @  Inbo Gottlieb-Fenves: my apologies - I thought I had fixed this before ... its now corrected

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture with score vs. time. Then each of your “possible ways” will correspond to a particular path in the plane from $(n, 6)$ to $(n+15, s)$ for each possible final score $s$. And you can weight each clock-tick step on a path by its probability. This visualization should help you figure out precisely what computation to perform.

Comment: @ Paul Tanenbaum: thank you for your reply! I am working on a similar visualization ....

Comment: The visualization you want is the [trinomial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle)

Answer (score 1):

You're just trying to find the size of the set$$A(n)=\{(x_1,\dots,x_{15})\in\{0,\pm1\}^{15}:x_1+\dots+x_{15}=n\}$$

for $n\in \{-15,\dots,15\}$. Here, $A(n)$ denotes the event that you "end up" at $n+6$ after $15$ turns assuming you begin at $6$.

Obviously $A(-n)=A(n)$ so we need only consider non negative values of $n$ for now.

The number of $-1$ terms in a $15-$tuple from $A(n)$ must be any one of

$$0,1,\dots,\lfloor{\frac{15-n}{2}}\rfloor$$

Observe: If there are $k$ entries of $-1$ in some $15-$tuple of $A(n)$ we must also have $k+n$  terms that are $+1$ and $15-(2k+n)$ terms that are $0$. So, $$|A(n)|=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{15-n}{2}}\rfloor}\frac{15!}{k!(n+k)!(15-n-2k)!}$$

Now extend this formula to $n\in \{-15,\dots,15\}$ by replacing $n$ with $|n|$. $$|A(n)|=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{15-|n|}{2}}\rfloor}\frac{15!}{k!(|n|+k)!(15-|n|-2k)!}$$

If instead you're trying to find the probability $$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_1 + \dots + X_{15}=n\Big)$$ where $X_1,...,X_{15}$ are iid with common that share a common pmf $$p(-1)=0.45=p(1) \text{   and    } p(0)=0.1$$ you can still proceed as we did above to get $$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_1 + \dots + X_{15}=n\Big)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{15-|n|}{2}}\rfloor}\frac{15!}{k!(|n|+k)!(15-|n|-2k)!}(0.45)^{|n|+2k}(0.1)^{1-|n|-2k}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Can you also solve this problem using a Random Walk/First Passage Time style approach?